# Build failed when generate signed APK with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to build my project, this error occurred:

```
    Error: "mail_subtitle" is translated here but not found in default locale [ExtraTranslation]
    Error: "login_subtitle" is translated here but not found in default locale [ExtraTranslation]
    Error: "password_subtitle" is translated here but not found in default locale [ExtraTranslation]
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /xxxxxx/src/main/res/values-es/strings.xml:336: Also translated here
   Explanation for issues of type "ExtraTranslation":
   If a string appears in a specific language translation file, but there is
   no corresponding string in the default locale, then this string is probably
   unused. (It's technically possible that your application is only intended
   to run in a specific locale, but it's still a good idea to provide a
   fallback.).
   Note that these strings can lead to crashes if the string is looked up on
   any locale not providing a translation, so it's important to clean them
   up.

  > Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
  To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          checkReleaseBuilds false
          // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
          // but continue the build even when errors are found:
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...
```

Ok, I know that the error is because I have strings translated (to Spanish and Portuguese), but i don't have the default translation. The problem is that my default translation is inside my library and not in this project.

The structure of the whole project NEED TO BE as described: the default translation inside the library and the translations inside this other project. All classes that use these strings are inside the library, and translations are inside the project that uses the library, because I need different translation for each project that i'm building.

Android Studio suggest a lintOptions "abortOnError false" but I don't want to use this flag, I wanna be advised when I build error occurs, I just don't wanna see this specific error.

Answer (score 1):

try adding strings.xml in your default values folder like /src/main/res/values/strings.xml ?

and then add the 3 missing strings in your default language.